# Which version of Visual Studio 2012 has the profiler? Professional / Premium / Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version, profiler

Microsoft web site has conflicting information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

> ... using the Profiling Tools of Visual Studio Premium and Visual Studio Ultimate to analyze performance issues ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264994.aspx

> Requirements
>
> - Visual Studio Ultimate, Visual Studio Premium, Visual Studio Professional

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare

> - Professional: Examine and refine your code with extensive tools for app debugging and profiling
> - Ultimate: Collect and analyze runtime diagnostic data from production systems
> - Ultimate: Perform unlimited web performance and load testing

I think I am right in saying that 2010 Professional did NOT have the profiler, and you needed Premium or Ultimate edition. Has this changed for 2012?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare is for VS 2017, now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These Visual Studio 2012 versions supports Profiling Visual Studio Ultimate, Visual Studio Premium, Visual Studio Professional

Answer (score 7):

VS 2012 Pro includes the profiler.